# Where have I errored in solving $\int\sqrt{1+\sin x}$ which lead me to two possible answers

Tags: calculus

The integral:$$\int\sqrt{1+\sin x}$$

I went at it like this:
$$\int\sqrt{\left(\sin{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos{\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2}$$
$$2\left(-\cos{\frac{x}{2}}+\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\right)$$

From here I can take a minus sign out or not do that to get $-2\sqrt{1-\sin x}$ and $2\sqrt{1-\sin x}$ the answer is the one with the negative sign in the front. I'm certain my mistake has to do with this last step but I just cannot put my finger on it.

From Arturo's comment I realise that $\cos{\frac{x}{2}}$ must be bigger than $\sin{\frac{x}{2}}$ since the answer with the negative sign is the correct one as per my book.

But why is this so ?

Comment: Remember that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, not $x$. That's why you have sign problems.

Comment: If the question asks about the indefinite integral on the whole real line, neither answer is correct, but perhaps, they just ask you to do it on a certain interval you forgot to mention...